# Internal vs external data type in oracle 19c

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle19c

I read long `Oracle documentation` , still could not understand what is difference and actual meaning of `Internal vs External datatype`. In `oracle 19c` I read internal vs external datatype.

Can somebody suggest, how below code is not compatible with `oracle19c`..it is just header. I think some `datatype` issue is there but not able to figure out.

I am not able to understand how below `package specificatio`n is not compatible with `oracle19c`. This file have been scanned invalid. Oracle docs is not helpful

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE ABC_ECC_DATASECURITY_PKG_PUB AS
/* $Header: ABCCCDSS.pls 120.0.12020000.2 2020/11/17 21:49:12 mgarg noship $ */

  PROCEDURE GetFilterAttributeValues
  (   p_dataset_key    IN         VARCHAR2,
      p_user_id        IN         NUMBER,
      p_org_id         IN         NUMBER,
      p_resp_id        IN         NUMBER,
      p_resp_app_id    IN         NUMBER,
      p_sec_group_id   IN         NUMBER,
      p_params         IN         ecc_sec_field_values DEFAULT NULL,
      x_return_status  OUT NOCOPY VARCHAR2,
      x_return_message OUT NOCOPY VARCHAR2,
      x_sec_filter     OUT NOCOPY CLOB
  );

END ABC_ECC_DATASECURITY_PKG_PUB;
/

COMMIT;
EXIT;
```

Can somebody suggest me `oracle internal and external datatype` and any help in above `specification`?

I read this in oracle docs.
[image]

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnoci/data-types.html#GUID-D69455D9-CE01-44CC-B5A9-E541C7774805

here it is mentioned `internal vs external datatype`.
https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnoci/data-types.html#GUID-027FB2E2-593C-43F1-9184-DFEF7A984A27

Comment: What do you mean by "This file have been scanned invalid."? If you're getting an error message, it would help if you edited your question and printed the full error message, along with which tool generated the error message. What do you mean by internal versus external data types - are you using OCCI or some other tool to connect to the database?

Comment: @JonHeller  Thanks Jon, I have updated the question. actually we are migrating our application from 12c to 19c(ADB) so release team has highlighted that these files needs to be changed. I am just going through documentation and editing them. I thought this is small file so might be datatype issue.I have modified the question. Please help.

Comment: "internal" data types are known as the "built-in"  and they are listed in table 5.1 of the ref you gave above. by inference therefore "external" data types are those that might be encountered from some other source. *"An external data type code indicates to Oracle Database how a host variable represents data in your program. This determines how the data is converted when it is returned to output variables in your program, or how it is converted from input (bind) variables to Oracle Database column values."*

Comment: Thanks Paul. could you please give one example?

Comment: When you say "release team has highlighted that these files needs to be changed" - what exactly did they say needs to be changed? I don't see anything obviously wrong with the package specification. Maybe there's an issue with the custom type `ecc_sec_field_values`?

Comment: You quote the OCI programmers guide. That will most likely not help you, as it is for C or C++, while your code looks like PL/SQL. Secondly, the CLOB in your case looks fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your package is fine, if you leave out the user defined datatype `ecc_sec_field_values`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE ABC_ECC_DATASECURITY_PKG_PUB AS

  PROCEDURE GetFilterAttributeValues
  (   p_dataset_key    IN         VARCHAR2,
      p_user_id        IN         NUMBER,
      p_org_id         IN         NUMBER,
      p_resp_id        IN         NUMBER,
      p_resp_app_id    IN         NUMBER,
      p_sec_group_id   IN         NUMBER,
      x_return_status  OUT NOCOPY VARCHAR2,
      x_return_message OUT NOCOPY VARCHAR2,
      x_sec_filter     OUT NOCOPY CLOB
  );

END ABC_ECC_DATASECURITY_PKG_PUB;
/

Package ABC_ECC_DATASECURITY_PKG_PUB compiled
```

However, if you include `ecc_sec_field_values`, I'm getting an error:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE ABC_ECC_DATASECURITY_PKG_PUB AS

  PROCEDURE GetFilterAttributeValues
  (   p_dataset_key    IN         VARCHAR2,
      p_user_id        IN         NUMBER,
      p_org_id         IN         NUMBER,
      p_resp_id        IN         NUMBER,
      p_resp_app_id    IN         NUMBER,
      p_sec_group_id   IN         NUMBER,
      p_params         IN         ecc_sec_field_values DEFAULT NULL,
      x_return_status  OUT NOCOPY VARCHAR2,
      x_return_message OUT NOCOPY VARCHAR2,
      x_sec_filter     OUT NOCOPY CLOB
  );

END ABC_ECC_DATASECURITY_PKG_PUB;
/

Error(9,35): PLS-00201: identifier 'ECC_SEC_FIELD_VALUES' must be declared
```

I guess this is a `TYPE` declared in some other file. Look for `CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE ecc_sec_field_values` or something.

BTW, the `COMMIT` seems dangerous, as the original author seems not to understand the commit behaviour of `CREATE` statements...